# Dual/Double List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I am looking for a way to store two `List<int>` objects. I am currently using a `List<List<int>>`, but that seems wasteful to only use `[0]` and `[1]`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Loot at stroring pairs of ints: `List<Tuple<int, int>>`

Comment: What's the problem with having two List<int>s? Could you describe what you are trying to achieve in a little more detail? Tuple<List<int>, List<int>> is also an option :)

Comment: I agree with @qqbenq. It depends on context if they're logically linked then hold them in a class?

Comment: Please explain *what* kind of information you store in these lists, and why only 0 and 1 are used

Comment: Apart from the tuple which you should use only in a method context, you can create a class which has two properties with meaningful names. Then use a `List<YourClass>`. It's much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I'm really tempted to flag this question to get it put on hold until the OP provides more information, the answers submitted so far may be correct but also may not be the solution required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Tuples:

```
var t = Tuple.Create(new List<int>(), new List<int>());
```

Then just access `t.Item1` and `t.Item2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Servy to pointing out, I've missed the point.
OP wants to create composite `List<int> + List<int>`, rather than a `List<int+int>`.

```
public class Pair<T>
{
    public T Left { get; set; }
    public T Right { get; set; }

    public IntPair(T left, T right)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }
}

    //or you might want more flexibility
public class Pair<TLeft, TRight>
{
    public TLeft Left { get; set; }
    public TRight Right { get; set; }

    public IntPair(TLeft left, TRight right)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }
}
```

---

Create your own data type to hold both integers

```
public class IntPair
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public IntPair(int a, int b)
    {
        this.A = a;
        this.B = b;
    }
}
```

If the list isn't required to be returned, only used temporarily.
There is also the anonymous type.

```
//or generate this from the existing data
var pairs = Enumerable.Empty<object>()
                      .Select(o => new { A = 0, B = 0 })
                      .ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    pairs.add(new { A = i, B = i * 2 });

//do more with pairs...
```

Comment: This is a waste, just use `Tuple` instead.

Comment: @DavidG tuple is the worst thing in C#, not only my opinion. It takes 15 seconds to write class with descriptive name and properties

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy In many circumstances yes, but to store a very simple pair of values, why not?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy If Microsoft would show tuples some love in form of syntatic sugar, then they would be great...

Comment: A pair of lists and a list of pairs are two very different things.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy And to call it the "worst thing in C#" is hyperbole.

Comment: @DavidG agree, with names `IntPair`, `A`, `B` its not good solution, thats why I wrote comment under question :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Agreed, which is why I (and I suspect you) have held off giving an answer until the OP provides some more context as to what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @sloth To get what you want, the ability to dynamically define the names of the variables, can be done using `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject` already.  If you want to keep your code statically typed though, that's not an option at all.  To maintain static typing would be to *radically* change the C# language specs (and wouldn't actually require CLR support).  I *highly* doubt that would happen.  You can get close with anonymous types, but they can't function properly outside of the scope of a single method body.  Allowing *that* would be...problematic.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Indeed they are bad names, but given the context. You can't deduce any more appropriate names.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Then you should wait for more context before providing an answer.

Comment: @Servy When did I talk about the ability to dynamically define the names of the variables?

Comment: @sloth What else would you intend to do with `Tuple`?  What problems do you have with it *other* than the fact that the variable names aren't meaningful?  You were also responding to a comment about having unmeaningful variable names, so there's a pretty strong implication that that is what you have a problem with.

Comment: @Servy OP is only using the [0] and [1] of the tier-2 list. That why I replace it with a new type.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 He's only using two values in the *outer* list, because *he has exactly two lists* as he said.  He made no statement about each of the inner lists having two values.  Again, he said that he wants to have two lists, not a list of pairs.

Comment: @Servy Ah, ok, I see. The comment I replied too was edited. It just read *tuple is the worst thing in C#, not only my opinion.* when I replied. As for syntactic sugar: when writing something like `var a, b = Tuple.Create("Foo", 123)`, it would be nice if the compiler would rewrite it to `Tuple<string, int> __temp  = Tuple.Create("Foo", 123); string a = __temp.Item1; int b = __temp.Item2;`. But for this to work, implicitly-typed local variables would need to allow multiple declarators; and this is a huge topic of its own.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Your code is still essentially re-implementing `Tuple` and calling it `Pair`

Comment: Your re-implementation of `Tuple` is also missing out on a number of the features of `Tuple`; it's simply an inferior version of it.

Comment: The point to avoid having `Tuple<This,That>` flying everywhere. Admittedly, they are convenient; However, `Item1` or `Item2` provide very limited information other than the type. By using a class, you can give a more meaningful name like `OddNumbers` and `EvenNumbers`.